# Sticky Footer conflict css

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer, sticky

I'm trying to use a sticky footer, but it seems to having a conflict with my css, I'm following [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) tutorial, but I want to know why the footer is in the middle of the page, what do I have to do to fix it.

My code:

jsfiddle.net/q2Vuq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing this strange behaviour with the sticky footer is because of your usage of `position:absolute;` on a number of your elements. Namely, the ones wrapped within the `#navigation` div.

[Take a look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/q2Vuq/2/) (this JSFiddle just illustrates the problem more clearly):

I've given the offending elements all a background colour (as well as the body), so you can see that these elements are actually causing the scroll bar to extend beyond the height of the body. Absolute positioning actually takes them outside of the layout - meaning they don't cause their parent `#navigation` to expand, which in turn does not cause its parent `.page-wrap` to expand, which ultimately results in the footer not getting moved down. The footer gets put to the bottom of the body (as a result of the sticky footer CSS), which isn't quite low enough since the absolute-positioned elements extend even further below (as they are ignored by the body).

So, with that in mind, how do you fix this behaviour? Unfortunately, your sticky footer relies largely on the assumption that all content will be figured into the layout above it, or at least that the wrapper element above it will be tall enough to account for all its contents. This makes your use of absolute positioning hard to keep.

The best solution is probably to remove your current usage of absolute-positioned elements in your document, and rework how you're going to place your elements. Since I don't know what design you're actually aiming for, I can't provide an example of this. An alternative is to place an internal wrapper element inside of `.page-wrap`, with a `min-height` set such that it goes below even the lowest absolute-positioned element. However, this second method isn't too flexible, and I wouldn't recommend it.

If this isn't what you were looking for, or need more assistance in this particular matter, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your answer, based  on this exemple http://cinemaclassico.com.br/ of design could you help me, the difference is that I have a fixed top bar and I want to add that sticky footer, How can I replace the absolute-positioned elements?

Comment: Well, it's hard to give a definite answer without knowing the intended position of the `#navigation` div's children. Right now, they'd look out of place even if they were figured into the layout - can you specify to which parts of the example design these elements would correspond to?

Comment: On the left, where is the categories: ação,aventura... that would be the #categoria, the #navigation would be the bar that contains the search box, and where is the content would be the #apDiv2 wich is the editable template.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Unfortunately, although I was fussing with this layout for a bit, it became apparent to me that I won't be able to help you lay this out in its current state.

The main problem is that the HTML from the PHP includes is unknown to me, so I'm not sure how certain elements (such as the `#categoria` element you mentioned) would be nested. A JSFiddle loses some usefulness when part of the document is missing.

Comment: ok, but based on this layout:jsfiddle.net/q2Vuq/ how would you solve that? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, all right. I removed a lot of your HTML and included only the elements you were concerned with, along with much of the CSS in order to make the code more readable and useable. Take a look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42muG/5/. That's one way (and probably one of the simpler ways), you could achieve the layout suggested. (Try zooming out to see the sticky footer work.) I hope this helps you!